# Create dynamic function with arguments using Symfony4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am new in symfony 4 and I've done the CRUD. I want to enhance my code by creating a function that will lessen it.

Example:

If you have 2 modules like manage event and announcement(ofcourse you will have here add,get all,delete, and update). Instead of having a long code like this.

```
 $fetch_item = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository(Event::class)
                    ->findAll();
```

I want to short it like $fetch = $this->fetch(Event::class); I created a new file in my Service directory.

**Service\Crud.php**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * 
 */
class Crud extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function fetch($table)
    {
        $fetch_item = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository($table)
                        ->findAll();

        return $fetch_item;
    }
}


?>
```

**Controller**

```
//
...
use App\Service\Crud;

    ...
    class EventController extends AbstractController
     public function index()
        {
            // $fetch_item = $this->getDoctrine()
         //                 ->getRepository(Item::class)
         //                 ->findAll();
            $fetch = $this->fetch(Item::class);
            return $this->render('base.html.twig',array(
                'items'         => $fetch_item

            ));
        }
```

Above is my code but it gives me an error "Attempted to call an undefined method named "fetch" of class "App\Controller\ItemController""

Question: How can I create a function that will lessen my code?

Comment: Does your Controller extends the Crud class ?

Can you share the whole header of your classes please ?

Comment: Do I need to extend it? I thought as long you import(use App\Service\Crud) it will now work. My controller extends to AbstractController

Comment: You need to extend Crud from Event controller if you want to use it like that.

Comment: Is my approach correct? Or did I miss something in my service file

Comment: That’s a lot of work to save 2 lines of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for the fetch function to be part of a controller (on the contrary there are lots of reasons not to be). What you need is a simple service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CrudService {

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function fetch($entityClass) {

        return $this->em->getRepository($entityClass)->findAll();

    }
}
```

Then in your controller you just have to inject it through autowiring and use it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Service\CrudService;
use App\Entity\Item;
...

class EventController extends AbstractController {
    public function index(CrudService $crudService) {
        $items = $crudService->fetch(Item::class);

        return $this->render('base.html.twig',array(
            'items' => $items
        ));
    }

}
```